# show ipad2 camera in fullscreen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad-2

I want to show `UIImagePickerController` in fullscreen mode for iPad2.
`presentModalViewController:` appears not work for me.
It show the frame with capture button but not show video preview of what is being capture?

Anyone got same problem before and now how to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the AVFoundation framework,
the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer can then be set to full screen.

Comment: You mean, I will present my UIImagePickerController as normal, then add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as a imagePicker sub-layer? Do you have any idea why if I present imagePicker in a popOverView, preview layer is shown, but not with presentModal?

Comment: Nope: under AVFoundation, you don't use UIImagePickerController any more (there's example code at Apple's). For the presentModal, I believe it's a matter of where you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
controller.allowsEditing = NO;
controller.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Note that self is the current view controller.